# Getting new Context State after Context State is updated

Tags: reactjs, state, react-context

I have a child component inside a context provider. After a child component calls an update state to the context provider, the context provider's state changes. However, this new changed value is not attainable from the child state. How would I be able to retrieve the updated value of the changed state from the Child component?

Or... is this just a bad practice and is there another way to do this?

I have a Context State in a Context Provider

```
AuthContextProvider=()=>{
    const[data,updatedata]=React.useState(null)
    AuthUpdate function(){
       updateData() //updates the state
    }
    //... pass AuthUpdate, data to children
}
```

and a child component... as such

```
<AuthContextProvider>
   <NavBar>
   </NavBar>
</AuthContextProvider>
```

Navbar looks like this:

```
NavBar=()=>{
   const {data,AuthUpdate}=useAuth()
   onClick function(){
        AuthUpdate()  //data in the context changes
        console.log(data) //somehow use the UPDATED data after context state changes
   }

}
```

Comment: Can you point out a specific issue you are facing? Does your state change when you call update function?

Comment: @Enfieldli Yes. State changes in the context. State does not change in the child component. How would we get it to change in the child component?